# Location not coming on Account if I am using inline attribute

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, inline-visualforce, inline, detail-page

I have overridden my Account standard page. Below is the code

```
<apex:page id="overridepg" standardController="Account" extensions="ActivityOverride_ctlr" action="{!redirect}">   
   <apex:detail relatedList="true" showChatter="true" inlineEdit="true" id="dtlpg" oncomplete="reloadPage();" /> 
   <c:DetailPageOverride />
</apex:page>
```

If I am removing the inline attribute from  tag then location map is coming on Account detail page and if I use it location map isn't coming.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are some conditions for using inlineEdit.

apex:inlineEditSupport

This component provides inline editing support to  and various container components. In order to support inline editing, this component must also be within an  tag.

```
The <apex:inlineEditSupport> component can only be a descendant of the following tags:
<apex:dataList>
<apex:dataTable>
<apex:form>
<apex:outputField>
<apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:pageBlockTable>
<apex:repeat>
See also: the inlineEdit attribute of <apex:detail>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have used the tags given in documentation but the same thing is happening.